# passing dynamic value from one jsp page to another using session on button click

Tags: java, jsp

I am making a job search web application using java. I have alotted a job id to each job and i am displaying the list of jobs in a bootstrap table from database. on each button click i need to forward this job id to a jsp page where i am adding the applicant name to the database corresponding to the jobs.My code is:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.dbutil.CrudOperation"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession" %>


<html>
<head>
      <title>Job List</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jobs.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

 <% Connection con = null;

            ResultSet rs = null,rs1=null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            HttpSession hs = null;
            hs=request.getSession();
            con = CrudOperation.createConnection();



                %>

<div class="container">



     <%String strsql = "select * from postjob1 where sr>0";
                    try {
                        ps = con.prepareStatement(strsql);

                        rs = ps.executeQuery(); %>








 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Job Id</th><th>Job Category</th><th>Available Posts</th><th>Required Qualifications</th><th>Salary Details</th><th>Location</th><th>Last date of application</th><th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <% while (rs.next()) {

                %>
    <tbody>

        <tr><td><%=rs.getString("id")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("jobcategory")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("available")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("requiredqualification")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("salarydetails")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("location")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("lastdate")%></td><td><a href="jobDetails.jsp"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="<% hs.setAttribute("ID",rs.getString("id")); %>" >View Details </button></a></td></tr>

    </tbody>
     <%}
                            } catch (SQLException se) {
                                System.out.println(se);
              }%>
  </table>

 </div
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am facing difficulty when I am retreiving the session value ID in other jsp page as i am getting id of the last row in the table irrespective of whichever button i click.Kindly help me run my code.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<% hs.setAttribute("ID", rs.getString("id")); %>
```

In the excerpt above, you are setting the session attribute "ID". After executing the `while` loop, it stores the **last** "id" value. The **same** value is recovered in the destination page, whichever the clicked link.

A possible solution is passing the id in the invoked URL to the following page.

```
<a href="jobDetails.jsp?idJob=<%=rs.getString("id")%>">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
```

You can recover the parameter in jobDetails.jsp using

```
request.getParameter("idJob")
```

Note: I'm a bit rusty in JSP. Maybe I've forgotten a quote or something, but that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks  a lot ..I have been trying this for long..finally This code worked..!!

Comment: @AkankshaSeth You're welcome. Be so kind to accept the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass job id like request's parameter.

For example you can call your jsp-page like that:

```
<a href="jobDetails.jsp?job_id=3" />
```

Where job_id is a parameter name and 3 is its value.

After that you can read parameter's value in your jobDetails.jsp in next way:

```
<%=request.getParameter("job_id")%>
```